# Насколько актуальна автоматическая вёрстка?

Tags: веб-программирование, html, frontend, вёрстка, css

Сейчас появилось достаточно много программ, которые по макетам генерируют HTML+CSS вёрстку. Подскажите, пожалуйста, способны ли они реально заменить работу верстальщика? Подскажите, пожалуйста, наиболее удачные, на ваш взгляд, примеры таких программ.

Answer (score 1):

Искуственного интелекта еще не изобрели...

Такая верстка актуальна только в очень-очень крайних случаях, для тех, кто не шарит в ней, и когда нужно быстро что-то показать... вообще так можно просто мокапить, а верстку все равно вручную верстать нормальную.

Answer (score 0):

[@vvtvvtvvt](/users/14942/vvtvvtvvt), верстка/натягивание шаблона - это куда больше, чем просто расположить элементы, обычно к этому добавляется адаптив (это еще легко реализуется автоматикой), плюс анимация и реакция шаблона на действия пользователя - тут вообще непонятно, как скармливать программе ввод.